# coin-slider js gallery, want to add fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gallery, transition

I have this script for flipping through a gallery of images but it doesnt come with a simple fade transition, after a lot of fiddling I havent been able to figure out a way to add it. I figured i'd be able to use css transitions or jquery's fadeIn() but it didn't seem to work.

Anyone able to implement this?

---

### css file

```
/*
    Coin Slider jQuery plugin CSS styles
    http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider
*/


.coin-slider { overflow: hidden; zoom: 1; position: relative; }
.coin-slider a{ text-decoration: none; outline: none; border: none; }

.cs-buttons { font-size: 0px; padding: 10px; float: left; }
.cs-buttons a { margin-left: 5px; height: 10px; width: 10px; float: left; border: 1px solid #B8C4CF; color: #B8C4CF; text-indent: -1000px; }
.cs-active { background-color: #B8C4CF; color: #FFFFFF; }

.cs-title { width: 545px; padding: 10px; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; }

.cs-prev, 
.cs-next { background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 0px 10px; }
```

---

### javascript

```
/**
 * Coin Slider - Unique jQuery Image Slider
 * @version: 1.0 - (2010/04/04)
 * @requires jQuery v1.2.2 or later 
 * @author Ivan Lazarevic
 * Examples and documentation at: http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/

 * Licensed under MIT licence:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
**/

(function($) {

    var params      = new Array;
    var order       = new Array;
    var images      = new Array;
    var links       = new Array;
    var linksTarget = new Array;
    var titles      = new Array;
    var interval    = new Array;
    var imagePos    = new Array;
    var appInterval = new Array;    
    var squarePos   = new Array;    
    var reverse     = new Array;

    $.fn.coinslider= $.fn.CoinSlider = function(options){

        init = function(el){

            order[el.id]        = new Array();  // order of square appereance
            images[el.id]       = new Array();
            links[el.id]        = new Array();
            linksTarget[el.id]  = new Array();
            titles[el.id]       = new Array();
            imagePos[el.id]     = 0;
            squarePos[el.id]    = 0;
            reverse[el.id]      = 1;                        

            params[el.id] = $.extend({}, $.fn.coinslider.defaults, options);

            // create images, links and titles arrays
            $.each($('#'+el.id+' img'), function(i,item){
                images[el.id][i]        = $(item).attr('src');
                links[el.id][i]         = $(item).parent().is('a') ? $(item).parent().attr('href') : '';
                linksTarget[el.id][i]   = $(item).parent().is('a') ? $(item).parent().attr('target') : '';
                titles[el.id][i]        = $(item).next().is('span') ? $(item).next().html() : '';
                $(item).hide();
                $(item).next().hide();
            });         


            // set panel
            $(el).css({
                'background-image':'url('+images[el.id][0]+')',
                'width': params[el.id].width,
                'height': params[el.id].height,
                'position': 'relative',
                'background-position': 'top left'
            }).wrap("<div class='coin-slider' id='coin-slider-"+el.id+"' />");  


            // create title bar
            $('#'+el.id).append("<div class='cs-title' id='cs-title-"+el.id+"' style='position: absolute; bottom:0; left: 0; z-index: 1000;'></div>");

            $.setFields(el);

            if(params[el.id].navigation)
                $.setNavigation(el);

            $.transition(el,0);
            $.transitionCall(el);

        }

        // squares positions
        $.setFields = function(el){

            tWidth = sWidth = parseInt(params[el.id].width/params[el.id].spw);
            tHeight = sHeight = parseInt(params[el.id].height/params[el.id].sph);

            counter = sLeft = sTop = 0;
            tgapx = gapx = params[el.id].width - params[el.id].spw*sWidth;
            tgapy = gapy = params[el.id].height - params[el.id].sph*sHeight;

            for(i=1;i <= params[el.id].sph;i++){
                gapx = tgapx;

                    if(gapy > 0){
                        gapy--;
                        sHeight = tHeight+1;
                    } else {
                        sHeight = tHeight;
                    }

                for(j=1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++){  

                    if(gapx > 0){
                        gapx--;
                        sWidth = tWidth+1;
                    } else {
                        sWidth = tWidth;
                    }

                    order[el.id][counter] = i+''+j;
                    counter++;

                    if(params[el.id].links)
                        $('#'+el.id).append("<a href='"+links[el.id][0]+"' class='cs-"+el.id+"' id='cs-"+el.id+i+j+"' style='width:"+sWidth+"px; height:"+sHeight+"px; float: left; position: absolute;'></a>");
                    else
                        $('#'+el.id).append("<div class='cs-"+el.id+"' id='cs-"+el.id+i+j+"' style='width:"+sWidth+"px; height:"+sHeight+"px; float: left; position: absolute;'></div>");

                    // positioning squares
                    $("#cs-"+el.id+i+j).css({ 
                        'background-position': -sLeft +'px '+(-sTop+'px'),
                        'left' : sLeft ,
                        'top': sTop
                    });

                    sLeft += sWidth;
                }

                sTop += sHeight;
                sLeft = 0;                  

            }


            $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
                $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show();
            });

            $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
                $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();
            }); 

            $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
                $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show();
            });

            $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
                $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();
            }); 

            if(params[el.id].hoverPause){   
                $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
                    params[el.id].pause = true;
                });

                $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
                    params[el.id].pause = false;
                }); 

                $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
                    params[el.id].pause = true;
                });

                $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
                    params[el.id].pause = false;
                }); 
            }


        };


        $.transitionCall = function(el){

            clearInterval(interval[el.id]); 
            delay = params[el.id].delay + params[el.id].spw*params[el.id].sph*params[el.id].sDelay;
            interval[el.id] = setInterval(function() { $.transition(el)  }, delay);

        }

        // transitions
        $.transition = function(el,direction){

            if(params[el.id].pause == true) return;

            $.effect(el);

            squarePos[el.id] = 0;
            appInterval[el.id] = setInterval(function() { $.appereance(el,order[el.id][squarePos[el.id]])  },params[el.id].sDelay);

            $(el).css({ 'background-image': 'url('+images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]+')' });

            if(typeof(direction) == "undefined")
                imagePos[el.id]++;
            else
                if(direction == 'prev')
                    imagePos[el.id]--;
                else
                    imagePos[el.id] = direction;

            if  (imagePos[el.id] == images[el.id].length) {
                imagePos[el.id] = 0;
            }

            if (imagePos[el.id] == -1){
                imagePos[el.id] = images[el.id].length-1;
            }

            $('.cs-button-'+el.id).removeClass('cs-active');
            $('#cs-button-'+el.id+"-"+(imagePos[el.id]+1)).addClass('cs-active');

            if(titles[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]){
                $('#cs-title-'+el.id).css({ 'opacity' : 0 }).animate({ 'opacity' : params[el.id].opacity }, params[el.id].titleSpeed);
                $('#cs-title-'+el.id).html(titles[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]);
            } else {
                $('#cs-title-'+el.id).css('opacity',0);
            }               

        };

        $.appereance = function(el,sid){

            $('.cs-'+el.id).attr('href',links[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]).attr('target',linksTarget[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]);

            if (squarePos[el.id] == params[el.id].spw*params[el.id].sph) {
                clearInterval(appInterval[el.id]);
                return;
            }

            $('#cs-'+el.id+sid).css({ opacity: 0, 'background-image': 'url('+images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]+')' });
            $('#cs-'+el.id+sid).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);
            squarePos[el.id]++;

        };

        // navigation
        $.setNavigation = function(el){
            // create prev and next 
            $(el).append("<div id='cs-navigation-"+el.id+"'></div>");
            $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();

            $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).append("<a href='#' id='cs-prev-"+el.id+"' class='cs-prev'>prev</a>");
            $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).append("<a href='#' id='cs-next-"+el.id+"' class='cs-next'>next</a>");
            $('#cs-prev-'+el.id).css({
                'position'  : 'absolute',
                'top'       : params[el.id].height/2 - 15,
                'left'      : 0,
                'z-index'   : 1001,
                'line-height': '30px',
                'opacity'   : params[el.id].opacity
            }).click( function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.transition(el,'prev');
                $.transitionCall(el);       
            }).mouseover( function(){ $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show() });

            $('#cs-next-'+el.id).css({
                'position'  : 'absolute',
                'top'       : params[el.id].height/2 - 15,
                'right'     : 0,
                'z-index'   : 1001,
                'line-height': '30px',
                'opacity'   : params[el.id].opacity
            }).click( function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.transition(el);
                $.transitionCall(el);
            }).mouseover( function(){ $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show() });

            // image buttons
            $("<div id='cs-buttons-"+el.id+"' class='cs-buttons'></div>").appendTo($('#coin-slider-'+el.id));


            for(k=1;k<images[el.id].length+1;k++){
                $('#cs-buttons-'+el.id).append("<a href='#' class='cs-button-"+el.id+"' id='cs-button-"+el.id+"-"+k+"'>"+k+"</a>");
            }

            $.each($('.cs-button-'+el.id), function(i,item){
                $(item).click( function(e){
                    $('.cs-button-'+el.id).removeClass('cs-active');
                    $(this).addClass('cs-active');
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.transition(el,i);
                    $.transitionCall(el);               
                })
            }); 

            $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id+' a').mouseout(function(){
                $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();
                params[el.id].pause = false;
            });                     

            $("#cs-buttons-"+el.id).css({
                'left'          : '50%',
                'margin-left'   : -images[el.id].length*15/2-5,
                'position'      : 'relative'

            });


        }




        // effects
        $.effect = function(el){

            effA = ['random','swirl','rain','straight'];
            if(params[el.id].effect == '')
                eff = effA[Math.floor(Math.random()*(effA.length))];
            else
                eff = params[el.id].effect;

            order[el.id] = new Array();

            if(eff == 'random'){
                counter = 0;
                  for(i=1;i <= params[el.id].sph;i++){
                    for(j=1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++){  
                        order[el.id][counter] = i+''+j;
                        counter++;
                    }
                  } 
                $.random(order[el.id]);
            }

            if(eff == 'rain')   {
                $.rain(el);
            }

            if(eff == 'swirl')
                $.swirl(el);

            if(eff == 'straight')
                $.straight(el);

            reverse[el.id] *= -1;
            if(reverse[el.id] > 0){
                order[el.id].reverse();
            }

        }


        // shuffle array function
        $.random = function(arr) {

          var i = arr.length;
          if ( i == 0 ) return false;
          while ( --i ) {
             var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
             var tempi = arr[i];
             var tempj = arr[j];
             arr[i] = tempj;
             arr[j] = tempi;
           }
        }   

        //swirl effect by milos popovic
        $.swirl = function(el){

            var n = params[el.id].sph;
            var m = params[el.id].spw;

            var x = 1;
            var y = 1;
            var going = 0;
            var num = 0;
            var c = 0;

            var dowhile = true;

            while(dowhile) {

                num = (going==0 || going==2) ? m : n;

                for (i=1;i<=num;i++){

                    order[el.id][c] = x+''+y;
                    c++;

                    if(i!=num){
                        switch(going){
                            case 0 : y++; break;
                            case 1 : x++; break;
                            case 2 : y--; break;
                            case 3 : x--; break;

                        }
                    }
                }

                going = (going+1)%4;

                switch(going){
                    case 0 : m--; y++; break;
                    case 1 : n--; x++; break;
                    case 2 : m--; y--; break;
                    case 3 : n--; x--; break;       
                }

                check = $.max(n,m) - $.min(n,m);            
                if(m<=check && n<=check)
                    dowhile = false;

            }
        }

        // rain effect
        $.rain = function(el){
            var n = params[el.id].sph;
            var m = params[el.id].spw;

            var c = 0;
            var to = to2 = from = 1;
            var dowhile = true;


            while(dowhile){

                for(i=from;i<=to;i++){
                    order[el.id][c] = i+''+parseInt(to2-i+1);
                    c++;
                }

                to2++;

                if(to < n && to2 < m && n<m){
                    to++;   
                }

                if(to < n && n>=m){
                    to++;   
                }

                if(to2 > m){
                    from++;
                }

                if(from > to) dowhile= false;

            }           

        }

        // straight effect
        $.straight = function(el){
            counter = 0;
            for(i=1;i <= params[el.id].sph;i++){
                for(j=1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++){  
                    order[el.id][counter] = i+''+j;
                    counter++;
                }

            }
        }

        $.min = function(n,m){
            if (n>m) return m;
            else return n;
        }

        $.max = function(n,m){
            if (n<m) return m;
            else return n;
        }       

    this.each (
        function(){ init(this); }
    );


    };


    // default values
    $.fn.coinslider.defaults = {    
        width: 565, // width of slider panel
        height: 290, // height of slider panel
        spw: 7, // squares per width
        sph: 5, // squares per height
        delay: 3000, // delay between images in ms
        sDelay: 30, // delay beetwen squares in ms
        opacity: 0.7, // opacity of title and navigation
        titleSpeed: 500, // speed of title appereance in ms
        effect: '', // random, swirl, rain, straight
        navigation: true, // prev next and buttons
        links : true, // show images as links 
        hoverPause: true // pause on hover      
    };  

})(jQuery);
```

---

### html

```
<head>

<!-- include the files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="coin-slider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="coin-slider-styles.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<!-- list the images to be in the show and any descriptions -->
<div id='coin-slider'>
    <a href="img01_url" target="_blank">
        <img src='img01.jpg' >
        <span>
            Description for img01
        </span>
    </a>
    ......
    ......
    <a href="imgN_url">
        <img src='imgN.jpg' >
        <span>
            Description for imgN
        </span>
    </a>
</div>

<!-- Insert the show -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#coin-slider').coinslider();
    });
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Under the default values at the end just change the values of spw and sph to 1.

Javascipt file:

```
spw: 1, // squares per width
sph: 1, // squares per height
effect: 'rain'
```

Comment: 1. Please use proper formatting. 2. how does your answer solve the problem? You simply specified random values.